# SAS Proc SQL Aggregate

Tags: sql, sas

An example of end results I have is

| CASEID | Transaction id | charge | sumofcharges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | $0.10 | $0.60 |
| 1 | 11 | $0.20 | $0.60 |
| 1 | 12 | $0.30 | $0.60 |
| 2 | 13 | $0.50 | $0.50 |
| 3 | 14 | $0.65 | $0.65 |
| 4 | 15 | $0.75 | $1.75 |
| 4 | 16 | $1.00 | $1.75 |
| 5 | 17 | $0.15 | $1.35 |
| 5 | 18 | $1.20 | $1.35 |

My end result the business would like to have is only display 1 aggregate total per caseid.
for case id 1, .60 would only show one time and the rest blank. Is this possible? I'm using sum(charges) as sum_of_charges which of course gives me the totals. I need to leave the transaction ID in there. I do have other fields as well however transaction ID is the outlier.

Comment: Please show expected output and whatever you have tried. If you need transaction ID but they are different and multiple you will need to combine them somehow. How would you like that displayed?

Comment: Thats the thing I have no idea what to try on this one. Transaction IDs are different and multiple. Unfortunately this ID is required to leave as is for the business to do their work. I'm unable to combine them.

for example expected output for caseID 1 under sum of charges everything would be the same but display $0.60 one time and have 2 nulls

Comment: Do you care which observation has the sum?

Comment: nope. as long as they are tied to the same case id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really do that with SQL as it is designed to do SET operations and not process observations individually.

But once you have the sum calculated it is easy to use a data step to set all but one per CASEID to missing.

```
data want;
  set want;
  by CASEID ;
  if not first.caseid then sumofcharges=.;
run;
```

If the TRANSACTIONID value is UNIQUE within each value of CASEID you could use that to drive a CASE clause in PROC SQL.

```
proc sql ;
 create table want as
   select *
        , case when (transactionid=min(transactionid)) then sum(charge)
          else . end as sumofcharges
   from have
   group by caseid
 ;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This will work. I'm still fairly new to coding so I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN transaction_id = max(transaction_id) OVER (
                PARTITION BY caseid ORDER BY (
                        SELECT NULL
                        )
                )
            THEN sum(charge) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY caseid ORDER BY (
                            SELECT NULL
                            )
                    )
        END AS total
FROM test;
```

output data:

| caseid | transaction_id | charge | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0.10 | null |
| 1 | 11 | 0.20 | null |
| 1 | 12 | 0.30 | 0.60 |
| 2 | 13 | 0.50 | 0.50 |
| 3 | 14 | 0.65 | 0.65 |
| 4 | 15 | 0.75 | null |
| 4 | 16 | 1.00 | 1.75 |
| 5 | 17 | 0.15 | null |
| 5 | 18 | 1.20 | 1.35 |

Comment: "window" functions are not implemented in PROC SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can `left join` the original data with its aggregations.

Example:

Presumes `txid` unique within case and hopefully across all data.

```
data have;
input 
CASEID Txid charge dollar7.2;
format charge dollar7.2;
datalines;
1   10  $0.10   
1   11  $0.20   
1   12  $0.30   
2   13  $0.50   
3   14  $0.65   
4   15  $0.75   
4   16  $1.00   
5   17  $0.15   
5   18  $1.20   
;
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select have.*, aggregate.CaseChargeSum
  from
    have
  left join
    ( select caseid, min(txid) as mintxid, sum(charge) as casechargesum
      from have
      group by caseid
    ) aggregate
  on
    have.caseid = aggregate.caseid
  & have.txid = aggregate.mintxid
;
```

For good measure, the old school technique of `MEANS` then `MERGE`

```
proc means noprint data=have;
  by caseid;
  var charge;
  output out=agg sum=chargesum;
run;

data want;
  merge have agg;
  by caseid;
  if not first.caseid then call missing(chargesum);
run;
```